# Join Error: com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException: Client is not, or no longer, connected

Tags: android, kotlin, quickblox

I'm trying to use quickblox for a chat but I getting the fallowing error: com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException: Client is not, or no longer, connected in join QBResponseException

```
fun CreateDialog(){
        val occupantIdsList = ArrayList<Int>()
        occupantIdsList.add(128780267)

        val dialog = QBChatDialog()
        dialog.type = QBDialogType.PRIVATE
        dialog.setOccupantsIds(occupantIdsList)


        QBRestChatService.createChatDialog(dialog).performAsync(object :
            QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: QBChatDialog?, params: Bundle?) {
                Log.e(TAG, "result:       $result")
                result!!.lastMessage = "hey"
                JoinDialog(result!!)
            }

            override fun onError(responseException: QBResponseException?) {
                Log.e(TAG, "${responseException}")
            }
        })
    }



fun JoinDialog(dialog: QBChatDialog){
        Log.e(TAG, "Joinnnn:    $dialog")
        val history = DiscussionHistory()
        history.maxStanzas = 0
        dialog.join(history, object : QBEntityCallback<Void> {
            override fun onSuccess(o: Void?, bundle: Bundle?) {
                SetConnection()
                SendMessage(dialog)
                Log.e(TAG, "Join Good")
            }

            override fun onError(e: QBResponseException?) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Join Error: $e")
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before joining the dialog can you please try the following

```
dialog.initForChat(QBChatService.getInstance());
```

I think the client is not connected because of the connection being lost. So you can give it a try by initializing just before joining the dialog.

Comment: I got this error: "Recipient ID can't be null or empty"